# Change comments ordering by custom value

Tags: plugins, comments, sql

I added functionality to vote (up/down) on comments. I store the votes data in a custom table:

```
CREATE TABLE comment_vote (
  comment_vote_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  post_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  comment_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  user varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  vote tinyint(1) NOT NULL, -- value is '1' (up vote) or '-1' (down vote)
  PRIMARY KEY  (comment_vote_id),
  KEY post_id_comment_id_vote (post_id, comment_id, vote),
  UNIQUE post_id_comment_id_user (comment_id, user),
  FOREIGN KEY (comment_id) REFERENCES wp_comments(comment_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES wp_posts(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

The votes of a comment is calculated by

```
SELECT SUM(vote) FROM comment_vote 
WHERE comment_id = ...;
```

My aim is to display the comments ordered descending by votes (top-voted comment first).

A simple SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_comments 
WHERE post_id = ...
ORDER BY (SELECT SUM(vote) FROM comment_vote WHERE comment_id = wp_comments.comment_ID) DESC
```

Is there a way to sort comments *like this* or may it be better to achieve this by *storing the votes in `commentmeta` table*?

Comment: Note that because this data is being stored in a custom table it is impossible to order using comment query parameters, you're forced to introduce custom SQL via filters. That's not to say what you wanted is no longer possible. You could also have used comments themselves to store your votes by specifying a custom comment type, though how you'd then order that so that comments with the most replies of type vote are higher up would be a whole question in of itself. You'd also have the issue with comment meta that you can't order by structure data, you'd need a comment meta with a count/total

Comment: Thank you. If storing the total votes in commentmeta: I wonder if this may lead to performance issues. Do you know if each call of get_comment_meta results in an additional db query?

Comment: it depends if you tried to be clever about things or not. E.g. some people fetch posts and ask for only the post IDs to be clever and save bandwidth, only for it to then perform lots of tiny small queries to fetch individual post meta and terms that would normally have been fetched in bulk and stored in WP_Cache. This can also be an issue for custom tables as WP can store post meta/taxonomies/etc in persistent object caches and WP_Cache, but with a custom table you have to do all of this yourself and most people are totally unaware WP_Cache is even a thing leaving lots of performance untapped

Comment: the irony is, they created a custom table to make things fast, but unless you've got well designed indexes that are tailored to pre-planned database queries that's rarely the case. Note that WP tables are designed to be used in a particular way, but it's still possible to use them differently despite performance issues for utility purposes, e.g. searching for posts via `meta_query` or random ordering are fundamentally slow. For comment meta, all the equivalent functions and APIs exist as they do for post meta, e.g. `pre_get_comments`/`meta_query`/`get_comment_meta`/custom comment types/etc